# send an email for each result of mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, email

i have a 2 tables in my db, i did a query to verify if the email address is not present in both tables, list all users, now the email is what i use to verify that user is unique. i ran my script and it works perfect, i do an echo and i get 10 iterations (10 diferent users that email is not duplicated). now i need to send an email for each iteration, the issue is that when i add my mail fucntion i'm only receiving the 1 user and only 1 emai is sent, missing out 9 users more. how can i accomplish 10 users, 10 emails one for each user.

```
  <?php
 include 'myDB.php'; 

$sql = " query works fine ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//var_dump($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  foreach ($row as  $key => $gtm) {
   $message .= $gtm;
    $header ="From: no-reply@testme.com" . "\r\n";
    $para    = 'web2@tesy.com';
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $titulo  = 'Mailing list Newsletter';
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<br/> <p>El siguiente usuario abandono el la compra de un paquete en booking hello </p><br/>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="2">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["nombre_del_paquete"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Precio Total del paquete:</strong> </td><td>". $row["precio_total"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["nombre"]. "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Apellido:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["apellido"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";

    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";



    if(mail($para, $titulo, $message, $header)){
        echo "recorded successfully";
                die();
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }

    }

 }
 } else {
echo "0 results";
 }


 ?>
```

now when i added the mail fucntion is when i get 1 user only(the 1 one), if i remove mail function and do an echo i do get all users(10)

Comment: _please_ cleanup your code

Comment: You are sending it to just one email address use $row["email"] in the $header like $header ="To: " . $row["email"] . "\r\n";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `die()`:

```
foreach ($row as  $key => $gtm) {
    // more cod here:

    // your problem is in this if:
    if(mail($para, $titulo, $message, $header)){
        echo "recorded successfully";
        // die(); this stops the execution
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: i did this, but i got like 400 mails and is just 10, where do or how do i set a break here, if in the future i have 15,20 whatever, based the the amout of users it stops and dont keep sending the same user multiple tiles

Comment: my first question would be: why `foreach` in a `while`. Take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/Bsp6wk8k I reworked your script a bit

Comment: i did and i removed it, had it lil messy but by simply removing die() it works perfectly, thanks alot

Comment: happy to help ;)